# Firebase Auth Back Button

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

The firebase authentication in my android app does not have a back button. I want to be able to navigate back to the main activity if onActivityResult produces a cancel result.

How do you enable this? I am using the pre built authentication.

```
    final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
    );

    Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .setTheme(R.style.FirebaseUI)
            .build();

    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Comment: If you are asking how to change the way Firebase-UI works, you can do anything you want by simply copying its source code and adding what you want: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `super.onBackPressed()` will navigate back to previous activity

I assume you are using firebase google authentication. The following snippets of code might help you navigate back to the MainActivity if any failure has occurred.

For starting the authentication, call the `signIn()` method

If any API exception has occurred, `onActivityResult()` method will navigate back to previous activity

```
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    private void signIn () {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent ();
        startActivityForResult ( signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN );
        //Show user that authentication has started
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data ) {
        super.onActivityResult ( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent ( data );
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult ( ApiException.class );
                assert account != null;
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle ( account.getIdToken () );
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Toast.makeText ( this, "Google Sign In failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                mGoogleSignInClient.signOut ();
                mAuth.signOut ();
                //Show user that authentication failed
                //In your case navigate to MainActivity()
                super.onBackPressed (); //Navigates to previous activity
            }
        }
    }
```

The following code checks if the returned user is valid or not. If not navigates back to previous activity

```
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle ( String idToken ) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential ( idToken, null );
        mAuth.signInWithCredential ( credential )
                .addOnCompleteListener ( this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful ()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser ();
                        if (user != null) {
                            //Authenticated successfully
                        } else {
                            //Try to authenticate again
                            //This might not happen in most scenarios
                            signIn ();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText ( this, "Google Sign In failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut ();
                        mAuth.signOut ();
                        //Show user that authentication failed
                        //In your case navigate to MainActivity()
                        super.onBackPressed (); //Navigates to previous activity
                    }
                } );
    }
```

I hope this answer may help you

Comment: Isn't it just easier to call `finish()` to stop the current activity and go back?

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson!. Yes, you are right. Calling `finish()` method will stop the current activity and navigates the user to previous activity. As @onStackOverflowListener question was like, how to navigate back, I just used `super.onBackPressed()` method to do the purpose. And one more advantage is `finish()` can't be overridden. But `onBackPressed()` can be overridden, which may help further adding functionality while navigating to previous activity.

Comment: I am using the built-in auth system. Is the only way to do this by writing my own authentication flow.